# How to add an output for each number input?

Tags: c, counter, draw

I'm tasked with writing a short program that will allow a number input from 1-50, and from that number a triangle made of asterisks will output that many stories tall. For example, 
an input of 2 would output a * triangle that has one * at the top and a second row of two * at the bottom
and an input of 3 would output a * triangle that has one * at the top and a second row of two * in the middle, then a third row of three * at the bottom and so on. 
I know a way to do this by making a nested if gate for each number 1-50, but i was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

I know a way to do this by making a nested if gate for each number 1-50, but i was wondering if there was a more efficient way of doing this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void) 
{
    //gather user input
int triNum;
char a;
scanf("%i", &triNum);
    //make sure input is <= 50
if(triNum <= 50)
{
    if(triNum == 1)
    {
        printf("*");
    }
    if (triNum == 2)
    {
        a = '*';
        printf("*\n");
        printf("*%c\n", a);
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

When coding each individual number there is no actual error message I was just wondering a more efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably going to want to use loops for this, like shown in the program below. Then you don't need to treat each case separately.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int h, i, j;

    printf("What is the height of the triangle? ");
    scanf("%d", &h);

    for (i = 0; i < h; ++i) {
        for (j = 0; j <= i; ++j)
            printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

For a given height `h`, this program loops over `h` lines and in each line outputs `h` asterisk characters. For example, for `h` taking up 1, 2, 3, and 5, the output looks like shown below.

```
What is the height of the triangle? 1
*

What is the height of the triangle? 2
*
**

What is the height of the triangle? 3
*
**
***

What is the height of the triangle? 5
*
**
***
****
*****
```

Comment: Agreed, I'd use two for-loops as well. Of course that scales horribly but that's kind of the nature of this task.

Comment: @DennisB a single-loop alternative would be to start out with an empty string (array of characters) and append one more `*` in each iteration, and print out this string at each step.

Comment: @guatgr eventually it will be same as using 2 loops.

Comment: @kiranBiradar you are right, `printf` should be O(n) in this case.